# ODBC error in PHP: "No tuples available at this result index"

Tags: php, sql

Been looking for this on Google for a while, but still looking.  Couldn't turn up anything on it.

Using PHP to query MS SQL Server via ODBC.  Code is below: (I've watered it down to bare-bones as I've tried to debug this)

```
    $SQL=<<<HEREDOC
DECLARE @weekStart SMALLDATETIME;
SET     @weekStart = DATEADD(d,0, DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()));
SET     @weekStart = DATEADD(d, 1-DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), @weekStart);

SELECT
    DATEDIFF(week, Run_Date, @weekStart)
                            AS weeksAgo

    ,MIN(Current_List)      AS list

    ,COUNT(*)               AS cnt

    ,SUM(NoContact_90Days)  AS noContact90
    ,SUM(NoContact_180Days) AS noContact180

    ,SUM(NoMtg_180Days)     AS noMtg180
    ,SUM(NoMtg_360Days)     AS noMtg360
FROM
    [someDB].[DBO].[someTable]
WHERE
    Current_List<>''
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(week, Run_Date, @weekStart)
    ,Current_List
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, Run_Date, @weekStart)

;
HEREDOC;


    $dbUser = "someUser";
    $dbPass = "somePw";
    $connStr = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=someServer;';

    $conn = odbc_connect($connStr, $dbUser, $dbPass)
        or die("Cannot start ODBC connection");

    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $SQL);
    $r = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
    die('ok');
```

Getting a warning I've never seen on the odbc_fetch_array() line:

```
Message: odbc_fetch_array() [function.odbc-fetch-array]: No tuples available at this result index
```

I've run the query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio and it returns a single set of records.  I'm using this same connection string & method of retrieving the rows in other parts of the app with no problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: "and it returns _a single set_ of records" - I think that's worth testing in your php script too, especially since it's as easy as `while( odbc_next_result($rs) ) echo '#';`

Comment: Thanks, VolkerK.  I'll try that out tomorrow when I get into my office.

Comment: @VolerK:  Aha!  It's returning _two_ results.  Thanks for the tip.  Any idea why?  It's a straightforward query, I thought.  Maybe because it's more than a single statement?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer apparently (see comments) was that there is more than one result set and the first one couldn't be handled odbc_fetch_array().
You can switch to the next result set via [odbc_next_result()](http://docs.php.net/odbc_next_result)

[Multiple result sets returned from php ODBC query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601954/multiple-result-sets-returned-from-php-odbc-query) will probably include a discussion on why there are multiple result sets for this particular query.

Answer (score 3):

Every SET command "returns result set", therefore you can use `odbc_next_result() ($n-1)` times before `odbc_fetch_array(or smth else)`. Where $n - number of rows

```
$n = 0
while (odbc_next_result($some_result)) $n = $n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error mostly when I ran Stored Procedures from DB2 using PHP **odbc_connect**, however, everything ran fine after I changed the connection to use **PDO** prepare, execute, fetch statements.